# My previously used Dell laptop doesn’t show the Dell logo on boot but shows the logo of the organization that previously owned it

Tags: boot, dell-vostro

I received a Dell Vostro 3468 as a prize from a government organization.

When I boot it up, it does not show the default Dell logo, but instead it shows that government organization’s logo.

How can I remove that government organization’s logo and get the Dell logo to show up on start up?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about a different logo when the BIOS loads or just within Windows itself?

Comment: @wrecclesham At the time of Bios loading. Bios loads perfectly. Its just the logo that is annoying

Comment: Attaching a screenshot to it would be helpful to identify whether this logo in on Windows or on the BIOS load.

Comment: @CaldeiraG when i press the power button the first logo is the government's logo.After that comes the windows logo and then the usual sign in.By the way how to take screenshot without even completing the boot processs.

Comment: @CopperGolie Understood now. You can take a picture with your phone for example.

Comment: @CopperGolie Not familiar with Dell particularly, but at least in some instances it is possible to simply turn off the BIOS boot logo in the BIOS itself. It might not change the logo, but you may not have to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove that logo on the BIOS you will need to flash the BIOS with the original file from [Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/vostro-14-3468-laptop/drivers).

Search for "BIOS" and you should find a file called "Dell Vostro 3468 and 3568 System BIOS" released on 13 Aug 2019.

That will download a executable you can run to update the BIOS.

The executable looks like this:

[image]

Clicking on Continue should flash the BIOS.

You can also check Dell's page on [how to update the BIOS](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln284433/what-is-bios-and-how-to-update-the-bios-on-your-dell-system?lang=en).

**Be aware that flashing a new BIOS, if installed incorrectly, it can break your PC entirely**. So proceed with caution.

Comment: What precautions should i take i'm using 32 bit windows 10 pro.

Comment: @CopperGolie running the executable should work with no problems but updating the BIOS is still a advanced process.

Comment: @CopperGolie - You should verify your machine is charging when you flash the firmware.